# How do I run amddriverdownloader.exe on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-device-driver, display-driver

I downloaded `amddriverdownloader.exe` to update my Radeon HD 5450 on Ubuntu 11.10.  When I run it it returns with this:

```
jack@myComputer:~/Downloads$ amddriverdownloader
amddriverdownloader: command not found
```

The utility is supposed to detect the operating system and the need for drivers.

Comment: exe is a windows application. You should install from their restricted drivers.

Comment: Plus you would need to run ./amddriverdownloader.exe to run it from the current directory as Downloads is probably not in your path and you would still need to provide the full name ie amddriverdownloader.exe all this is irrelevant for the bigger picture as as @BlueMerlin already explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux doesn't run .exe files unless you have [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) or something similar. Anyway, Windows drivers would never work on Linux. There are specific drivers for every different kind of operating system.

Proprietary drivers are usually kept up-to-date in Ubuntu under "Additional Drivers" (you can load it from the main menu or by searching for "driver" if you use Unity). Check there first to see if the most recent Fglrx driver is turned on.

If you still want to install it manually, go to [AMD Support & Drivers](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) and enter the values of your system, and you will given a .run file, which is a bin file and will work just fine.